# AndroidJUnit4 Test: Keep activity alive

Tags: android, junit4

I'm trying to keep my activity alive after a certain test has finished with [AndroidJUnit4](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/runner/AndroidJUnit4.html). The reason why I want to do this is that sometimes I just want to see how the UI looks like and how the haptic feels like. For purposes like that, I don't want to build the whole app and navigate to the desired sites.

I read, that it's possble to override the [tearDown()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/InstrumentationTestCase.html#tearDown()) in order to prevent closing the activity.

Though the [InstrumentationTestCase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/InstrumentationTestCase.html) is deprecated and Android suggests to use the [InstrumentationRegistry](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/InstrumentationRegistry.html) and that new tests should be written with the new [Testing Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/testing-support-library/index.html).

How does it work to keep the activity alive after the test finished by using this new library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me. If you have better suggestions, please let me know.

[AndroidJUnit4](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/runner/AndroidJUnit4.html) does have tearDown and setUp, though it's not an override. It must be implemented by using an annotation:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    //do something
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    //do something
}
```

In order to keep the activity alive after the test passed, I let the thread wait in the tearDown method:

```
@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    synchronized (this) {
        wait();
    }
}
```

If you like to wake up the thread after a certain time (but I would suggest to use Thread.sleep() in that case) or if you like to trigger a wake up call, you can easily combine the synchronised block with a lock.